# Linq to entities prob after update to MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

i'm facing another problem after updating to MVC 5.

i've a function that check if a thing was do at a date :

```
UserProfile user = bdd.UserProfile.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == UserName);
return bdd.Pointage.Any(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.DateP) == Convert.ToDateTime(date) && p.User.UserId == user.UserId);
```

but now, after update to MVC 5, i've an exception when i execut this one.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)'

i've read here some similar problems with this exception, but i don't find any solution, and why it work before the update and no after...

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since user can be null, `FirstOrDefault` returns null if there isn't any userprofile with username equals to UserName, we have to make a check in the return statement:

```
return user!=null 
&& bdd.Pointage.Any(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.DateP) == Convert.ToDateTime(date) && p.User.UserId == user.UserId);
```

This change will not solve your problem, but it should be done. The problem you have is associated with the use of `Convert.ToDateTime` method. This is not a problem of MVC. This is happening because we cannot make use of this method in this context. The reason why we can't use it, is the fact that entity framework doesn't know how to translate this method call properly and send it to the database.

What can you do? One option that I could think is depended on the format of your strings, `p.DateP` and `date`. **Provided that** they both have the same format, you could just rely on comparing the string values.

```
return user!=null 
&& bdd.Pointage.Any(p => p.DateP == date && p.User.UserId == user.UserId);
```

Comment: Thank's, it made it before to see your answer, i don't why i want to convert if it's the same format... Thank you :)

Comment: @MauriceChocoswiss You are welcome dude. I am glad that I helped